# WPF Window assigning event handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, rider

I was trying to assign event handlers for WPF window (window B) just like it was assigned in window A, but IDE says `Cannot access non-static event PreviewKeyDown in static context`. Perhaps anyone knows the reason why it's like that. I don't see any differences between two windows.

Window A:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowA"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PreviewDetailWindow"
    Height="512.929"
    Width="809.152"
    MinWidth="240"
    Name="FormWindow"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Background="Gray"
    UseLayoutRounding="True"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

[image]

Window B:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowB"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BasketMap"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PlayerWindow"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    Background="Gray">
```

[image]

Notice that using `this.PreviewKeyDown` works well on both, but I'm just curious about why former way doesn't work well on two windows.

Comment: Please include enough code for us to understand what `PlayerWindow` and `FormWindow` are.

Comment: More code would be useful but the error message seems to suggest that on your PlayerWindow the PreviewKeyDown and PreviewKeyUp events are declared as non-static and when referencing members by class name rather than instance name only static members will be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowB does not have a name assigned to it:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowB" ... x:Name="PlayerWindow" ...>
```

Comment: @Ed I didn't notice that in one window it was `Title` and `Name` in annother. This probably will be helpful for others in same situation.